# How to simplify else-if statements where text string evaluation has the same name as array getting appended to? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, foreach

The following is a series of else-if statements, where once evaluated, appends data to an array with the same name as the hard-coded strings in the evaluation statement. I know there must be a fairly easy way to make this more efficient but I cannot think of a solution that doesn't over complicate things.

Code:

```
name = [];
name2 = [];
name3 = [];
name4 = [];
name5 = [];
name6 = [];
name7 = [];
name8 = [];
name9 = [];
name10 = [];
name11 = [];
name12 = [];
name13 = [];

if (categoryObject.category === 'name1') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name1.push(element);
});
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name2') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name2.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name3') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name3.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name4') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name4.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name5') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name5.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name6') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name6.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name7') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name7.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name8') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name8.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name9') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name9.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name10') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name10.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name11') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name11.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name12') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name12.push(element);
    });
} else if (categoryObject.category === 'name13') {
    categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
        // console.log('y: ' + element);
        this.name13.push(element);
    });
}
```

Comment: `this[categoryObject.category].push(element)`?

Comment: My post has "this" because it is called inside of: export class AppComponent implements OnInit { ngOnInit() { } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a dynamic approach, and omit local variables which have nothing to do with `this`.

```
categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
    // create array, if not exist
    this[categoryObject.category] = this[categoryObject.category] || [];
    // push value
    this[categoryObject.category].push(element);
});
```

Comment: Do the values pushed to the arrays need to be declared prior (like var name = [];) to the function so there is some type of storage, or does this create and store the values and arrays long enough for whatever usage needed in the mean time?

Comment: `push` is a method of Array. you have to initialise an array first before pushing. the length of the array is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Since your category key corresponds to your array variable names you can use a dynamic key based on the category.

Furthermore, you can use concat to copy all the values in your yAxis data into your arrays without the need to loop through each item.

```
// Stores the dynamic key
const key = categoryObject.category;

// Appends an array of variables (yAxis data) to one of your arrays using a dynamic key
this[key].concat(categoryObject.data.yAxis);
```

Comment: Added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could store the arrays in an object and use the category as the key.

```
var storage = {
  name: [],
  name2: [],
  name3: [],
  name4: [],
  name5: [],
  name6: [],
  name7: [],
  name8: [],
  name9: [],
  name10: [],
  name11: [],
  name12: [],
  name13: []
}
categoryObject.data.yAxis.forEach(element => {
  // console.log('y: ' + element);
  storage[categoryObject.category].push(element);
});
```