# Dynamically create dataset objects for multi-line graphing, using pre-defined dataset object arrays (JavaScript / Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, chart.js

How would I modify this code to dynamically create dataset objects inside of the 'datasets' array for each y-value data array that already exists? This is executed in the same function block as the function adding data to the arrays (where both fall inside of `export class AppComponent implements OnInit { ngOnInit() { } }`), answered previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710201/5067233 (as to provide proper source code credit).

My current method is obviously hard-coded and not efficient nor dynamic.

My generic code:

```
one = [];
two = [];
three = [];

...code that adds data to the arrays

    // The actual graph formatting
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.one,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: this.two,
            label: 'two',
            yAxisID: 'two',
            borderColor: '#3CBA9F',
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            data: this.three,
            label: 'three',
            yAxisID: 'three',
            scaleOverride: true,
            borderColor: '#51b7ed',
            fill: false,
          },
          ...n amount of datasets here
        ]
      },
    });
```

Comment: What does the array, where the data is coming from, look like? You can just map over that array and return an object with the appropriate properties for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi-line chart will have three important object arrays that need to be created, assigned to:

1. `chart.data.labels` - for x-axis labeling (ex. an independent variable like time)
2. `chart.data.datasets` - for y-axis labeling (including multiple lines)
3. `chart.options.scales.yAxes` - for the properties of the line(s)

If you have a pre-existing set of data (in this particular case `objectArray`) that contains pre-existing data associated with particular line names, you can create a constant array that contains strings of the same names (in this case `NAME_ARRAY`), as well as temporary arrays for each dataset (`name1 = []; name2 = [];` etc...) acquired by iterating through a for loop.

This can be seen with:

```
// 'N' PRE-DEFINED CONSTANTS

// Names of the lines you are graphing
const NAME_ARRAY = [
  'name1',
  'name2',
  'name3'
];
// Colors of lines in same order as aforementioned names
const HEX_ARRAY = [
  '#3CBA9F',
  '#51b7ed',
  '#FF0000'
];

// GRAPHING LINE PROPERTIES SHARED BY 'N' LINES

// Doesn't require arguments so can utilize .map() effectively
const datasetLineArray = NAME_ARRAY.map((value,index,array) => {
  return {
    id: value,
    display: false,
    ticks: {
      // INSERT YOUR PROPERTIES HERE (although none required)
      // max: 1000,
      // min: 100000,
      // reverse: true,
      // stepSize: 10000,
      // suggestedMax: 500,
      // etc...
    },
  };
});
// Utilizes two arguments so needs object creation upon call rather than pre-defined array mapping (as in .map())
function addDataToDataset(dataArray, index) {
  const tempObject = {
    data: dataArray,
    label: NAME_ARRAY[index],
    yAxisID: NAME_ARRAY[index],
    borderColor: HEX_ARRAY[index],
    fill: false,
    scaleOverride: true,
  };
  return tempObject;
}

// CHART.JS GRAPH CREATION

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    // Store dataset objects
    Dataset_Object_Array = [];

    // Store data with same name as incoming objects
    name1 = [];
    name2 = [];
    name3 = [];

    // Essentially main()
    ngOnInit() { 
        for (const categoryArray in objectArray) {
            const categoryObject = objectArray[categoryArray];
            // these names are arbitrary, just note that categoryObject is an object that contains 
            // the property 'category' which is the equivalent of the name from the constant array 
            // 'NAME_ARRAY'; however, this object may contain data that we need to parse

            // IMPORTANT BIT
            this.Dataset_Object_Array.push(addDataToDataset(this[categoryObject.category], categoryArray));
        }

        // The actual graph formatting
        this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                // **IMPORTANT BIT**
                labels: this.one, // x-axis labeling

                // **IMPORTANT BIT**
                datasets: this.Dataset_Object_Array // multi-line y-axis labeling as well as data
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                legend: {
                  display: true
                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                          return parseFloat(value).toFixed(3);
                        },
                    }
                 }],

                 // **IMPORTANT BIT**
                 yAxes: datasetLineArray, // property meta-data for the lines
               }
            }
        });
    }
}
```